# Negative Binomial MGF converges to Poisson MGF

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, convergence, negative-binomial-distribution, moment-generating-function

This question is Exercise 3.15 in [Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger](http://amzn.to/2cVB1P4). It asks to prove that the MGF of a Negative Binomial $\mathscr{N}eg(r,p)$ converges to the MGF of a Poisson $\mathscr{P}(\lambda)$ distribution, when 
$$r\to\infty\,, \quad p\to 1\,, \quad r(1-p)\to\lambda$$

The formula I have for the MGF of $X\sim \mathscr{N}eg(r,p)$ is:

$$M_X(t) = \frac{p^r}{[1-e^t(1-p)]^r}$$

Considering just the denominator, we have 
$$[1-e^t(1-p)]^r = [1+\frac{1}{r}e^tr(p-1)]^r = [1+\frac{1}{r}e^t(-\lambda)]^r$$ As $r\to\infty$, this converges to $e^{-\lambda e^t}$. Now considering the entire formula again, and letting $r\to\infty$ and $p\to 1$, we get $e^{\lambda e^t}$, which is incorrect since the MGF of Poisson($\lambda$) is $e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$. I seem to be on the right track, just made a misstep somewhere. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You make a mistake by ignoring $p^r$:* If you consider your MGF $$M_X(t) = \frac{p^r}{[1-e^t(1-p)]^r}\,,$$
then $$\log\{M_X(t)\} = r\log(p)-r\log\{1-e^t(1-p)\}$$ and using the asymptotic equivalences
\begin{align*}
r\log(p)-r\log\{1-e^t(1-p)\}
&= r\log(1-[1-p])-r\log\{1-e^t(1-p)\}\\
&\approx -r[1-p]+re^t(1-p)\\
&\approx \lambda[-1+e^t]
\end{align*}
which shows that the limiting value of the MGF is
$$ \exp\{\lambda[e^t-1]\}$$ as requested in this exercise.

> **Note:** There are two versions of the MGF for a eg(n,p) distribution,
>   one for the number of trials and one for the number of failures. The
>   current version is the MGF for the number of failures, which starts at
>   zero like the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Thanks! My initial thought was to take the log of the MGF like you did, since the final expression is an exponential, but I got stuck with that approach. Just to be clear, you used the fact that $\log(1+x)\approx x$ for small $|x|$, which follows from the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I use the first order expansion of $log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\eqalign{    M_{x}(t)&=\left[\frac{p}{1-\frac{e^{t}(1-p)}{p}}\right]^r \\
             &=\left[\frac{1-(1-p)}{1-\frac{e^{t}(1-p)}{p}}\right]\\
             &= \left[\frac{1-\frac{r(1-p)}{r}}{1-\frac{e^{t}r(1-p)}{rp}}\right]\\
             &=\frac{e^{-r(1-p)}}{e^{{-e^{t}}r(1-p)}}\\
             &=e^{-\lambda}e^{e^{t}\lambda}
}$$
by applying the given conditions, and we have the desired result

Comment: I fixed the $\TeX$ markup by making minimal changes, so all the errors in this analysis are yours to fix!

Comment: I don't follow the next to the last step. Equality doesn't apply to the last step you need to show how it converges in the limit. Note 1-x is not equal to $e^-$$^x$

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was correct that you ignored the numerator $p^r$, but I found the illustration is a little confusing, so here we go for a standard way to solve the problem

$\begin{aligned} \lim_{r\to \infty} M_{NB}(t) & = \lim_{r\to \infty} (\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^t})^r \\ &= \lim_{r\to \infty} (\frac{1-(1-p)}{1-(1-p)e^t})^r \\ &= \lim_{r\to \infty} \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{r}(-\lambda))^r }{( 1+ \frac{1}{r}e^t(-\lambda))^r } \quad \quad r(1-p) =  \lambda \Rightarrow 1-p = \frac{\lambda}{r} \\ &=  \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{e^{-\lambda e^t}} \\ &= e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}  \end{aligned}$

which is the $MGF$ of Poisson Distribution

Note: Lemma 2.3.14 in the Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger book states a useful limit where when we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{a_n}{n})^n = e^a$